# expand div or UL based on content overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml

How can i make the div expand when there is lots of content within it?

**HTML:**

```
<div class ="content">
    this is a test <br />
    this is a test <br />
    this is a test <br />
    this is a test <br />
    this is a test <br />
    this is a test <br />
    this is a test <br />
</div><br />
<div class="click-here">Click here to see more</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.content
{
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div.click-here
{
    border:1px solid green;
    width:200px;
}
```

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/nvCvy/1/

Jquery or CSS?

Would a jquery scroll be a better solution? or would you display everything using css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the expansion would be height only and be on click of the button you could do:

```
​$('.click-here').click(function() { 
    $('.content').css('height', 'auto');
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nvCvy/3/

Comment: It's just css issue and don't require jquery code to resolve this.

Comment: Based on the mark-up I am making the assumption that the OP wants to expand on click of a button

Answer (score 4):

You need to do below two changes.

1. Don't mention the height i.e. remove `height` property.
2. remove `Overflow:hidden;`

Below is the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/SqMBQ/). You can add as much content as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery assuming you want the user to click the button:

http://jsfiddle.net/nvCvy/2/